# Chat bubble animation

Tags: android, animation, chat

I want to achieve animation when I send my message it goes from bottom to top like flying a bird (though I have done it :P) but while flying, that chat bubble view's radius is also changing(This is the thing I am not able to achieve).

Please help me to achieve this kind of animation or give me some sort of hint.

Thank you

I have used below code to set radius and then translate that view using xml file but not able to change radius on the go.

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();

            // Specify the shape of drawable
            gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);

            // Set the fill color of drawable
            gd.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // make the background transparent

            // Create a 2 pixels width red colored border for drawable
            gd.setStroke(2, Color.RED); // border width and color

            // Make the border rounded
            gd.setCornerRadius(15.0f);

            ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlvView)).setBackground(gd);

             Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.item_animation_from_bottom);

            ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlvView)).startAnimation(animation);
```

[image: Chat animation]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please check this link how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Nikola : please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ObjectAnimator (derivative class of ValueAnimator) to achieve animate any value (visible/invisible) of a view. Code below animate cornerRadius for one time from 15.0f to 0. Please try, I hope it helps.

```
     // Make the border rounded
    gd.setCornerRadius(15.0f);
    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlvView)).setBackground(gd);

    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(gd, "cornerRadius", 0);
    animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(800);
    animator.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, sure I'll try your suggestion, but one thing I would like to know that is it possible to reduce radius while on the go like my radius begin to decrease when animation starts (for ex. radius is 8 then it starts to decrease 8,7,6,5,4 and so on..)

Comment: You need delayed start if I didn't misunderstand your question Try this: animator.setStartDelay(300);

Comment: No sir, not delayed start, As you can see in above GIF when I send message my bubble view is having rounded corner in the starting but when my view is going to top side it's radius is changing and at last point it is having sharp corners, I hope you got my point

Comment: The code I gave in answer changes the cornerRadius from 15 to 0. You need to combine it with a transition animation. So, you will have a rectangle that moves and changes radius You can use AnimatorSet to animate both transitions together. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet